# How do I fix this 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.models.target_python'?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, pycharm

I am new to python and was testing some things out I had seen online.

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://techwithtim.net")
```

But I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\absol\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have already successfully used `pip install selenium` and other variations which after trying to repeat them they inform me that requirements are already met. IDLE will tell me the `selenium` version when I ask for it.

I then tried the "Python Packages" tab to manually install selenium but it returns the following error message:

```
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 73, in run_pip
    runpy.run_module(module_name, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 226, in run_module
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 98, in _run_module_code
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\absol\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main
  File "C:\Users\absol\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\Users\absol\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\Users\absol\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "C:\Users\absol\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip._internal.models.target_python import TargetPython
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.models.target_python'
```

And it suggests to run the following:

```
(venv) C:\Users\absol>C:\Users\absol\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3/plugins/python-ce/helpers/packaging_tool.py install selenium
```

Which returns this:

```
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\absol>C:\Users\absol\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\activate.bat

(venv) C:\Users\absol>C:\Users\absol\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3/plugins/python-ce/helpers/packaging_tool.py install selenium
C:\Users\absol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\\Program': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

(venv) C:\Users\absol>pip install selenium
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\absol\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\absol\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\Users\absol\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\Users\absol\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "C:\Users\absol\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip._internal.models.target_python import TargetPython
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.models.target_python'
```

*Note: I went ahead and tried `pip install selenium` again just because I saw the `(venv)`

At this point I just don't know where I should be looking. I thought maybe I just don't know how to deal with PyCharm virtual environments and should change to a different script writer. I would be open to that, or just a link to a comprehensive guide for me to read over how to fix PyCharm.

Any help or direction to some kind of video media is appreciated.

Edit/Update: I am able to run the code through IDLE and Jupyter. Although still get a "deprecation" message:

```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this commmand.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. 

Trying that gave me the following message:
```C:\Users\absol>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\absol\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (22.3.1)
```

Disclaimer: During my prior attempts to solve this issue I uninstalled both Python and PyCharm, then reinstalled them along with pip and selenium.